# Send Log File Changes Via Email

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, email, logging, alerts

I'm running Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition and need to send text log file updates to an email address. E.g. IIS logs, and other plain text files.

It would be good if these could be filtered before being email. Similar to logcheck in unix.

I'm happy to create a script or application, but thought there must be something free/open source available to do this.

Comment: I dont really full understand what you need, but I recomend using "blat" for the sending. It's lightweigh, no install, can use security... Nice app for sending.

Comment: I would liek an equivelent of logcheck designed to run in windows: http://logcheck.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, but I needed something more specific.

So I created a VB.NET application that will run hourly/daily and:

- it takes text based logs files plus the windows system events
- finds what has been added since last time
- parses the new events using regular expressions to ignore valid records
- emails new events

Answer (score 0):

Check out [log parser](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/03/25/analyze-your-iis-log-files-favorite-log-parser-queries.aspx).  It doesn't have an emailing component but it will certainly help with the filtering.  You can write a batch file to run log parser and save to a file that you email.  It supports checkpoints too so it remembers where it left off if you want to run it at regular interval and only report on the changes since last time.